# Spring boot standalone CommandLineRunner won't return with spring-starter-amqp

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm building a classic producer -> rabbitmq -> consumer flow.
All 3 nodes run on separate jvm even separate hosts

Producer is a spring boot command line runner app which is expected to stop when done producing.

Consumer app is a spring boot web application which listens to 3 rabbitmq queues (2 durable queues bounded to a direct exchange, 1 non durable bounded to a fanout exchange)

My boot sequence is the following:
- start rabbitmq
- start consumer
- start producer

Producer and consumer amqp dependencies `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
```

Producer code

```
/**
 * @author louis.gueye@gmail.com
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PlatformBrokerExampleProducerJob implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AmqpTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        final Instant now = Instant.now();
        final Instant anHourAgo = now.minus(Duration.ofHours(1));
        final String directExchangeName = "careassist_queues";
        final String fanoutExchangeName = "careassist_schedules_topics";
        IntStream.range(0, 60).boxed().forEach(i -> {
            final SensorEventDto event = SensorEventDto.builder() //
                    .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //
                    .businessId("sens-q7ikjxk1ftik") //
                    .timestamp(anHourAgo.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(i))) //
                    .state(SensorState.on) //
                    .build();
            final String routingKey = "care.events";
            template.convertAndSend(directExchangeName, routingKey, event);
            log.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Sent {} to exchange {} with routing key {}", event.getId(), directExchangeName, routingKey);
        });
        IntStream.range(0, 60).boxed().forEach(i -> {
            final SensorEventDto event = SensorEventDto.builder() //
                    .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //
                    .businessId("sens-q7ikjxk1ftik") //
                    .timestamp(anHourAgo.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(i))) //
                    .state(SensorState.off) //
                    .build();
            final String routingKey = "maintenance.events";
            template.convertAndSend(directExchangeName, routingKey, event);
            log.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Sent {} to exchange {} with routing key {}", event.getId(), directExchangeName, routingKey);
        });
        IntStream.range(0, 60).boxed().forEach(i -> {
            final SensorEventDto event = SensorEventDto.builder() //
                    .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //
                    .businessId("sens-q7ikjxk1ftik") //
                    .timestamp(anHourAgo.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(i))) //
                    .state(SensorState.off) //
                    .build();
            final ScheduleDto schedule = ScheduleDto.builder().id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //
                    .destination("any.routing.queue") //
                    .message(event) //
                    .timestamp(anHourAgo.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(i))) //
                    .build();
            final String routingKey = "#";
            template.convertAndSend(fanoutExchangeName, routingKey, schedule);
            log.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Sent {} to exchange {} with routing key {}", event.getId(), fanoutExchangeName, routingKey);
        });
    }
}
```

Consumer code (1 listener)

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = {PlatformBrokerExampleCareEventsQueueConsumer.QUEUE_NAME})
@Slf4j
public class PlatformBrokerExampleCareEventsQueueConsumer {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "care_events";
    @RabbitHandler
    public void onMessage(SensorEventDto event) {
        log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<< Received event [" + event + "] from {}...", PlatformBrokerExampleCareEventsQueueConsumer.QUEUE_NAME);
    }
}
```

I expect the producer to produce then shutdown, but instead, the java process hangs indefinitely

Any explanation as of why the producer won't stop after producing its messages would be greatly appreciated. I suspect it is related to `spring-started-amqp` but I'm not sure. I certainly don't need the full jar, just the little which contains AmqpTemplate

NOTE: consumers received all messages

github [project](https://github.com/lgueye/ha-playground/tree/master/platform/broker)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMQP client has some background threads.

You should change the `main()` method to close the application context after the runner returns...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args).close();
}
```

It will shut everything down cleanly as is less brutal than `System.exit()`.

Comment: will do. #TIL. I didn't know amqp was a connected protocol on the producer end. I'll investigate that part when I have some time

Comment: He has some threads handling the I/O to the broker, and to provide async delivery of publisher confirms/returns etc.

Answer (score 2):

PlatformBrokerClientConfiguration bind queue(s). But I can not see anywhere to close the queue. So that maybe the cause to suspend your instance.

Please try this.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(EmployeeDataProduceApp.class, args)));
  }
```

Comment: Hello @todaynowork

I don't think it's related to that. Producers and consumers can come and go, that won't affect the binging which it the equivalent of a database schema (meant to stay). The producer may stop but the consumer should continue listening in case another producer starts producing messages.

I would say that there is maybe a MessageListenerContainer automatically started by spring-boot (even if I don't see any valid reason since I did not declare any `@Listener` in the producer) but I'm not sure unless I investigate more deeply

Comment: You could try this.    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(EmployeeDataProduceApp.class, args)));
  }

Comment: Hey @todaynowork thanks for the suggestion. It worked. I still don't know the root cause for that hanging but it stopped cleanly

Comment: The AMQP client has some threads running; you can simply close the context after the runner exits and everything will be shutdown cleanly... `SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args).close();`

Comment: glad to know other approach to exit program